# Datorama Video dimensions data - what type of file should I use?

Tags: database, video, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I use Marketing Cloud Intelligence (aka Datorama) and I couldn't find in their documentation what file I can link to a video type dimension.

I tried using a shareable link from a Google Drive folder but the video doesn't display (even though I have a "play" button indicating the type of dimension in the dashboard).

Does anyone have an answer or at least a reliable documentation for this?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]